# How to install SQL Server 2008 in shared folder on network?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, networking, vpn

I need to install SQL Server 2008 in a specific folder of my system. The folder is sharing with all systems which are connected to my network.

1. How can I install SQL Server in a specific path?
2. How can I set SQL Server accessible to all systems?

Note: The systems connected through a **VPN**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't and you don't.

To share a SQL Server instance you install it on one server and you give access to clients on it. File sharing has **nothing** to do with it. Read [Server Network Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189083.aspx).

You mus properly license all users and machines accessing your shared server.